# Is it possible to use JWplayer within the Flexslider (JQuery) plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jwplayer, flexslider

I am designing a website for which I have a big banner (made with [flexslider](http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/)) that scrolls images as well as movies (which I would like to stream with [JWplayer](http://www.longtailvideo.com/players/jw-flv-player)).

Does anyone have any experience using a jwplayer video within flexslider? It does say on flexsliders' website that any html element is supported, but I would like to know from actual user experience whether this is possible or not (and I've not yet gotten an answer from woothemes, after many tries).

Or are there other, better solutions for embedding movies in flexslider?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you try it? Or is there some sort of weird restriction you are not mentioning? Because I downloaded both, included JWplayer into the flexslider example page and replaced one of the sliding images with a div and it worked fine.

Download both, unpack both into the same folder and in demo.html, replace the contents of one <li> with this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jwplayer.js"></script>
<div id="mediaplayer"></div> 
<script type="text/javascript">
    jwplayer("mediaplayer").setup({
        flashplayer: "player.swf",
        file: "video.mp4",
        image: "preview.jpg"
    });
</script>
```

Seriously, it could not be easier.

Comment: Yeah sorry, my question was a bit vague: I tried it, but what I came up with was rather unelegant. Which is why I was wondering if there was better way. And from your example I can see there is :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is an hackish example of jwplayer and flexslider working together 
http://jsfiddle.net/MCcy5/4/